# NSIS call powershell cmdlet Update-MpSignature not recognized as the name of a cmdlet powershell

Tags: powershell, nsis

I used NSIS call powershell update windows defender definitions, but when I use   **nsExec::ExecToStack '"powershell.exe" -c Update-MpSignature'**, it report an error "**Update-MpSignature** is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet powershell". I have tried call "powershell.exe" -c Update-MpSignature in cmd, it worked well.  I also have tried NSIS offical psexec.nsh ${PowerShellExecFileLog} call Update-MpSignature in ps1 file , other cmdlet like Get-ChildItem、Remove-Item can work very well, but still report an error "**Update-MpSignature** is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet powershell. Can somebody help me?

Comment: There is no official powershell header, you must be talking about the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a 64-bit issue.

On 64-bit systems you could try executing `$WINDIR\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe` like [this header file](https://gist.github.com/julianhille/e5f3ee50b11a77c4f77c855ae3d9c443) does.

Comment: I have tried user [this header file](https://gist.github.com/julianhille/e5f3ee50b11a77c4f77c855ae3d9c443) replace official psexec.sh, but it still report an error "Update-MpSignature is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet powershell".

Comment: Thanks for your help! it  really a 64-bit issue. I found use windows powershell can execute this cmdlet. But use windows powershell(x86) report an error "Update-MpSignature is not recognized as the name of a cmdle". I use   ${DisableX64FSRedirection}
  nsExec::ExecToStack '"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" Update-MpSignature'.It worked well.